# Перенести текст properties

Tags: java

Есть текстовый файл в котором строку "url" считываю через properties и вывожу текст на экран в виде рисунка с помощью paint(Graphic g), но у меня текст получается больше экрана и его некоторую часть не видно, можно ли как-нибудь считать количество символов в строке url и разделить их, перенеся на другую строку? Считывание знаю как делать, но проводить операции типа переноса на другую строку отдельной части символов или поставить ограничение кол-ва символов на 1 строку не знаю как делать((

Имеющийся код:

```
try {
            g.drawString(new String(props.getProperty("url").getBytes("ISO8859-1")), 200, 180);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
String check = null;
        check = props.getProperty("url");
        int lenth = check.length();
        if(lenth>10){
            //Вот тут проблема!
        }
```

Comment: Проблема в Swing? Почему используете вывод текста через draw? Почему не через JLabel?

Comment: Можно и через JLabel, но проблема остается в том, что я не знаю как переносить оставшийся текст на нужную мне область

Comment: Думаю, если есть необходимость показать полный URL, нужно пересмотреть дизайн формы.